Are similarity-preserving maps on matrix groups necessarily power series?
Let $n \geq 2$ and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ denote the set of all $n \times n$ matrices over the complex numbers. Does there exist a continuous map $f: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $$ A f(B) A^{-1} = f(ABA^{-1}) $$
for all $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (in other words, $f$ preserves similarity transformations), and $f$ is not expressible as a power series on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?
For $n = 1$, since $M_1(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}$ is commutative, any continuous map $f$ trivially preserves similarity transformations. However, for $n \geq 2$, I could not think of examples beyond power series. In particular, consider functions of the form $f(B) = BC$. Only when $C$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix does $f$ preserve similarity transformations.
The assumption of "continuity" in this question is necessary; otherwise, we could simply construct a map that takes a constant multiple of identity on each similarity equivalence class.
I thought of this question while studying Lie groups and Lie algebras, where many analytic functions from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to itself arise. It struck me that the property of preserving similarity transformations is highly non-trivial for analytic functions; we cannot expect a smooth function of infinite order to automatically have this property. In earlier studies of analytic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, I never noticed this property due to the commutativity of multiplication. It only becomes meaningful in the context of non-commutative Banach algebras.
However, in the case of matrix groups, I have not encountered examples of similarity-preserving matrix functions that are not expressible as power series. Does this mean all such functions must be power series? If counterexamples exist, I think they would be quite interesting.
I also wonder if this question can be approached from a "higher perspective." Is there any special significance to maps that preserve similarity transformations?

$f(X) = \text{Tr}(X)I$ is an example. To see that it cannot be expressed as a power series in $X$, simply consider its Fréchet derivative.
